# Improvements on a circuit that charges a battery from a solar cell

Tags: solar-cell, solar-charge-controller

I am working on the circuit in the picture below. This circuit represents how to power a battery from a solar cell.

[image]

I understand the logic behind the diagram but I was thinking what improvements to make to the circuit. I am new at electronics therefore I didn't have much ideas on what would be a good improvement.

Some ideas that I had was to use a mechanical arm for the solar cell so that it will follow the sun direction. But I am not sure if this improvement is related to the circuit.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Is this a school assignment, or is it something you are doing as a hobby (or personal learning) project?

Comment: @JRE I have to build this circuit for school. But the improvements are for personal learning.

Comment: If you understand it, break it apart into functional blocks.  Look for blocks that waste energy, or that don't do their jobs well.

Comment: @JRE does using a micro controller helps to control when to charge the battery and when to use that electricity of that battery to supply some other device

Comment: Also look for components that might be operating too close to their limits.  How much current will T1 have to pass, and how much power will it dissipate.

Comment: That would change the function of the circuit.  As it is, the circuit charges the battery.  Whatever is attached to the battery draws power as it needs it.  The charger section doesn't "care."  It never explicitly switches from a "charge" mode to a "supply" mode.  It just charges the battery when the battery voltage drops.

Comment: An MCU has pitfalls, if you are still learning, it's better to learn the analog technology first.